# JavaScript onClick change css

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

This is probably really simple, I know you can change css properties with javascript by doing;

```
document.getElementById('bob').style.background='#000000';
```

But I recently found out that you can do this differently and style multiple things, so something like this;

```
document.getElementById('bob').css='background:#ffffff; color: #000000;';
```

the problem is I have forgotten what the code, So what I basically want to achieve is what goes in instead of the ".css"? Does anyone know the code I need out the top of their head?

Comment: nope :( grrrr, should have written it down

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the `.cssText` property from `style`

```
document.getElementById('bob').style.cssText = 'background:#ffffff; color: #000000;';
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx5yH/

Comment: @Šime Vidas: as far as I can tell, yes! But I don't know about IE6 and below or FF < 3 for instance.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSJfz/

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').setAttribute('style', 'background: #f00; color: #fff;');
```

All I do is change the `style` attribute of the element, is that what you meant to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you is looking for is [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript). Since this way you don't need to hardcode all the style changes on the JavaScript itself (which is bad).

So you'll have a CSS class like it:

```
.myClass {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
```

And you'll set to your element like this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className += " myClass";
```

Comment: Yeh I know you can do it this way, but I think I need the .cssText for what I'm trying to do, but thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('bob').style.cssText = 
    'background:#ffffff; color: #000000;';
```